# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended Error with LIKE Sql Query

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am working with jdbc.I am getting a Exception with following preparedstatement

```
  PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement("select * from customer where INITIALIZED=1 && FILE_NAME LIKE ?");
  //filename is string
  pstmt.setString(1, "%" + filename + "%");
  rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
```

I am getting the following error

```
  016-06-01 18:59:55 ERROR DatabaseUtils:276 - java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at pe.entel.DatabaseInsertionandRetrieving.LocalDatabaseTransactImpl.retrievewithfilename(LocalDatabaseTransactImpl.java:279)
at pe.entel.DatabaseInsertionandRetrieving.LocalDatabaseTransactImpl.main(LocalDatabaseTransactImpl.java:287)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your query has a syntax error.
In SQL you need to use `AND` and not `&&`, as follow:

```
// Introduced sql only for a better reading
String sql = "select * from customer where INITIALIZED=1 AND FILE_NAME LIKE ?";
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
```